# Android ListView: Multiple contact numbers with check box under one contact name

Tags: android, eclipse, android-listview, android-contentprovider, android-custom-view

I wanted to show multiple contact number under one contact name. each number should have check box. I have done with this code which shows me one contact name with one number. if that contact name has another contact number it shows another number with same name.

**DisplayContacts.java**

```
//import statements 
public class DisplayContacts extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> phone = new ArrayList<String>();
MyAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);

    getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactListView);

    adapter = new MyAdapter();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    adapter.toggle(position);
}

public  void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null,null);
    while (phones.moveToNext())
    {

      String name1=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
      String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
      name.add(name1);
      phone.add(phoneNumber);
    }

    phones.close();
 }

class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
{  private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
   LayoutInflater mInflater;
    TextView textView1,textView2;
    CheckBox cb;
    MyAdapter()
    {
        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name.size());
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)DisplayContacts.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return name.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
         vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_item, null); 
        textView2= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         textView1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
         textView2.setText(""+ name.get(position));
         textView1.setText(""+ phone.get(position));
         cb.setTag(position);
         cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
         cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        return vi;
    }
     public boolean isChecked(int position) {
            return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
        }

        public void toggle(int position) {
            setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
        }
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {

         mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);         
    }   
}   
}
```

**activity_contacts.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.ashu.mycontactapp.Contacts" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contactListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**contact_list_item.xml**

```
\\for each row in list 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my Output screen shot

[image]

See avinash contact name in image above. it shows name twice. I wanted both numbers under one contact name.

Comment: Please suggest me something.